# XSLT ignore if contains 0 elements

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I ignore style if there are 0 elements?

```
<xsl:template match="DifferenceNodes">
        <div class="code">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="DifferenceNode"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
```

I want it to make `div` with class code only if `DifferenceNode` contains at least one element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the match criteria for the `DifferenceNodes`.  Add a predicate filter that ensures it only matches when there are `DifferenceNode` children.

```
<xsl:template match="DifferenceNodes[DifferenceNode]">
   <div class="code">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="DifferenceNode"/>
   </div>
 </xsl:template>
```